# JavaScript scope issue (this)

Tags: javascript

I have tried to organize my code in an object oriented way (as explained in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)). In my case however, *this* refers to the window object. Because of that I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined

in

> this.renderer.render(this.stage);

Why does this refer to the window object when it doesn't on MDN?

```
var GAME = GAME || {};

GAME.Application = function() {
    this.renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(800, 600,{backgroundColor : 0x1099bb});
    document.getElementById("game").appendChild(this.renderer.view);
    this.stage = new PIXI.Container();
    requestAnimationFrame(this.render);
}

GAME.Application.prototype.render = function() {
    this.renderer.render(this.stage);
}

var app = new GAME.Application();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets talk about `this`, context, and functions

A good way to think about it, is that `this` refers to the object on the left of the `.` of the method that calls it.

```
var someObj = {
    name:'someObj',
    sayName: function(){
        console.log(this.name);
    }
};

someObj.sayName(); // prints someObj
```

Functions that are not methods of an object are bound to the window object.

```
window.name = 'window';
function sayName(){
    console.log(this.name);
}

sayName(); //prints window
```

The above is equivalent to

```
window.sayName(); // window is on the left of the dot, so it is `this`
```

When you pass a method of an object as a parameter, or assign it to a variable, it loses its original context. Below, the sayName method of someObj loses someObj as the context and gains someOtherObj.

```
var someOtherObj = {
    name:'someOtherObj'
};

someOtherObj.sayName = someObj.sayName;

someOtherObj.sayName(); // prints someOtherObj
```

To get around it, You can bind a context to a function

```
var yetAnotherObj = {
    name: 'yetAnotherObj'
};

var sayYetAnotherObj = sayName.bind(yetAnotherObj);

sayYetAnotherObj(); // prints yetAnotherObj
```

Or pass an anonymous function that calls the the method on the object itself

```
var OneLastObj = function(){
    var self = this;
    this.someValue = aFunctionTakingAcallback(function(){
        return self.doSomeStuff();
    });
}
```

Something to remember when passing functions around as a parameters is that you are passing a reference to the function. The function itself is not bound to the object that it may be a method of.

Answer (score 4):

You need to bind your `render` function. This is probably the most straight forward solution.

```
requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
```

Or instead, you could do

```
var context = this;
requestAnimationFrame(function() {
  context.render();
});
```

Or you could avoid creating the free variable and use an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

```
requestAnimationFrame((function(context) {
  context.render();
})(this)));
```

Or, if you're using ES6, you can use an arrow function

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => this.render());
```

---

Another easy improvement you could make is passing the render element into your Application constructor

```
function Application(elem) {
  this.renderer = ...
  elem.appendChild(this.renderer.view);
}

new Application(document.getElementById("game"));
```